# how can i print a string only once?

Tags: java

Need to print `Unterschiede gefunden:` only once

```
while(sc.hasNextLine() || sc1.hasNextLine()) {
        i++;

        try {
            text1 = sc.nextLine();``
            text2 = sc1.nextLine();
        if(!text1.equals(text2)){


            System.out.println("Unterschiede gefunden:");
            System.out.printf("Zeile %d :\n",i);
            System.out.println(text1);
            System.out.println(text2);
        }
        }catch(NoSuchElementException nse) {
            text2 = " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take it out of loop

Comment: yes but then i have a problem reading all of my data from the text files

Comment: Take `System.out.println("Unterschiede gefunden:");` out of loop and [read about while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: i tried it with if statements but then it only reads a part of my data

Comment: i want to print that only if the lines don't match and not always

Answer (score 0):

Detecting if one text file differs from another. Once you have detected that one file line is different than the other file line then inform the User (as you are doing) and **break** out of the while loop from within your **IF** code  block so as to stop processing files lines, for example:

```
if(!text1.equals(text2)){
    System.out.println("Unterschiede gefunden:"); // Difference Detected!
    System.out.println("Zeile " + i + ":\n");     // At file line #.
    System.out.println("File A: " + text1);       // Text line in File A.
    System.out.println("File B: " + text2);       // Text line in File B.
    break;                                        // Break out of the WHILE loop.
}
```

You have also taken into consideration the fact that **File A** could contain more or less lines than **File B** which is good but you should really exit the **while** loop at this time as well since you now are certain that **File A** is different from **File B**, for example:

```
// These two variables are used to see which file
// contains more of fewer lines.
int fileACount = 0;
int fileBCount = 0;

// Read the two files...
while (sc.hasNextLine() || sc1.hasNextLine()) {
    try {
        String fileAText = sc.nextLine();
        fileACount++;
        String fileBText = sc1.nextLine();
        fileBCount++;
        if (!fileAText.equals(fileBText)) {
            System.out.println("Unterschiede gefunden:");
            System.out.printf("Zeile %d :\n", fileACount);
            System.out.println(fileAText);
            System.out.println(fileBText);
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
        // Using a Ternary Operator below so as to
        // indicate which file contains more lines.
        String fileWithMoreLines = fileACount > fileBCount ? "A" : "B";
        System.out.println("Files are different! File " + 
                fileWithMoreLines + " contains MORE Lines.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to close your files.